# Intel Rapid Storage Technology made HDD dissapear

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, raid, intel-rst

Recently my laptop stopped booting windows. When I turned it on, Intel Rapid Storage Technology 12.7.0.1936 window showed up and said, that one of my SSD volume is disabled and asked me to press CTRL+I to enter Configuration Utility. When I pressed that, I was only allowed to select `Reset Disks to Non-RAID` option. So I selected it, but windows still failed to start with a `Operation System not found` message.

So I changed the following settings in BIOS:

- SATA Operation: AHCI (instead of Intel Smart Response Technology)
- Intel Rapid Start Technology: Disabled (instead of Enabled)
- Boot List Option: Legacy (instead of UEFI)

Then I was able to launch windows setup from usb. Windows repair didn't help, I got `The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.` message. So I just temporary installed windows into SSD (during setup my 500GB HDD drive wasn't visible).

I even booted live ubuntu from usb and it didn't detect my HDD drive.

Also my HDD is not visible in BIOS. It shows `Fixed HDD: None`.

My laptop's specifications:

- Dell Inspiron 14 7000 Series 7437
- Intel Core i5-4210U CPU @ 1.7GHz
- mSata Device  LITEONIT LMS-32L6M m-(S1) 32GB
- Windows 8.1

**Does anybody know any tool or approach how to unlock my HDD from RST and make it visible again?**

Comment: I assume you were using the SSD to cache the HDD.  It sounds like the HDD simply died.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically disconnecting HDD cable and reconnecting it made my HDD visible again.

Then I just formatted my SSD and HDD and installed fresh copy of windows into SSD (I'm not going to use Intel RST again).

Comment: Nice Malvin. Glad you got this sorted. When I read "Reset Disks to Non-RAID", I thought you might have blown it up forever. +1

Comment: @Ramhound This *is* the author of the question.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  As you can see from Ramhound's comment, the sparseness of your post leaves it unclear if this was the complete solution.  Can you expand your answer a little to make it more complete and definitive for others who have a similar problem?  You can also accept your own answer, which will indicate that this was the solution.

Comment: @Malvin - If disconnecting the HDD solve the problem, you should indicate that it solved the problem, saying that it "helped" does not indicate it was the answer to the question.  It was not clear you were self-answering your question.

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry, I edited my answer.